# generate statistic dashboard on asp.net framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, angularjs, reporting-services, asp.net-mvc-5

i got a project where i must create à web application based on ASP.NET (C#), i need to  generate dynamic statistic into a dashboard, the data is  extracted from the database. the user can export to XML or CSV file. My database is on SQLserver express 2014 and i m using visual studio 2013.
Looking for advice, what sort of technology to study .
thanks.

Comment: there are lots of examples and many ways to skin this particular cat so to speak. I would suggest that you break it down into small pieces / steps in regards to what you are wanting to do.. you need to determine the layout of the web page, then determine what that static content will be and how you will render / display that meaning `Html Tables, <div>, etc` also what functions / methods you will use to allow the end user to use in regards export the data to csv or xml I would do some research on `DataTable to XML and DataTable to CSV` start using `GOOGLE` it's there for a reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Dali*, you haven't mentioned if you need to use `MVC` or `WebPages` for your project so I will assume it's `MVC`. However, you can apply the same steps to `WebPages` with slight modifications.

There are **MANY** ways to build a dashboard in ASP.Net. Each has its own pros and cons. Please, use your own judgement. This list is nowhere near complete so I would recommend to search possible options online.

**1. SSRS Dashboard**

Many developers think it's an outdated technology, and, while I agree with them, I still think it's worth to learn if you're trying to implement Reports repository with basic functionality (daily snapshots, parameter filtering, report scheduling). SSRS supports different formats like `Excel`, `HTML`, `XML`, `PDF`. It's easy to learn and very intuitive. It uses `Visual Basic` for scripting, and can be easily integrated in `.ASPX` web pages.

Take a look at some [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssrs%20dashboard%20examples&espv=2&biw=1803&bih=1018&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=U23SVJWkKMueNouYg6AC&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&dpr=0.9).

**2. R + MVC**

This is a good option for the `statistical` dashboard. I personally have no experience using `R` so I cannot tell for sure if it's a viable option in your case. However, it's something to consider when you do your research. Here is a good [example](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/creating-a-business-intelligence-dashboard-with-r-and-asp.net-mvc-part-1/) to get an idea.

**3. JavaScript Chart Library + MVC**

Here is good a [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616156/Simple-Dashboard). For the JavaScript library, you can use either [D3](http://d3js.org/) or [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). Both are great and powerful. Both can be easily integrated with .Net framework. Also, this option is recommended if you already know the `JavaScript`. There is no need to learn anything else.

**4. AnjularJS (or any other JS framework) + MVC (or RESTful API)**

This one is my favorite because it provides a lot of room for customization and is flexible enough to satisfy your client needs. Some developers avoid using `MVC` and replace it with `WebAPI` (or even `SignalR`). This also a great solution and allows you to reuse the code if you decide to build a public `API` based on your dashboard data in real time. [Here](http://arulselvan.net/mvc/realtime-dashboard-asp-net-signalr-angularjs-d3js/) is what I'm talking about.

**P.S.** In all these options, `SQL Server` is used as a main data storage that is why I decided not to include it everywhere. Since you are a .Net developer, it's an obvious choice that you stick with SQL Server, in my opinion.

Comment: well thanks for your detailed answer yes i m learning mvc 5 i m planning to give the user complete liberty on costumizing the n dashboards soo i think that SignalR +mvc with some those js librairy  is useful for that more than SSRS and R is that right ?

Comment: Again, it's hard to say because I don't know your project, your clients, your skills. If I were you, I would spend a little bit more time researching the topic.